# SQL looping instead of union and union all

Tags: sql, date, presto

I've table which contains users who opted for certain cc. I need to write a query to find how many ppl where there in those category at the beginning of each month since 2021-01-01.

The below query which i mentioned down will work if i create 11 union all statement

But I am looking something better than this. for each month I need to pass first date of that month in select statement as well as in where conditions.

I need to do it in mysql or presto both are fine.

```sql
select coalesce(s.country_id,1) as country_id,year(date('2021-11-01')) as year,month(date('2021-11-01')) as month,count(distinct user) as total_members 
from table s 
where date(cast(s.start_at as timestamp)) <= date('2021-11-01')
and date(cast(s.end_at as timestamp)) >= date_add('day', 1,date('2021-11-01')

union all 

select coalesce(s.country_id,1) as country_id,year(date('2021-10-01')) as year,month(date('2021-10-01')) as month,count(distinct user) as total_members 
from table s 
where date(cast(s.start_at as timestamp)) <= date('2021-10-01')
and date(cast(s.end_at as timestamp)) >= date_add('day', 1,date('2021-10-01')
```

Comment: Don't tag multiple different RDBMS, just tag the one you are using. This, however, is certainly not SQL Server as the above isn't valid T-SQL (`date` isn't a function, it's `DATEADD`, not `DATE_ADD` and `timestamp` is a deprecated synonym for `rowversion` to name a few reasons why).

Comment: Understood. Changed it to presto.

Comment: also provide sample data and desired output

Comment: Can you guys provide some solution ?